# Android How to focus on current position

Tags: android, google-maps, location

Hi I've an android app that finds your location on google maps, but when I've started the app it started from Africa not in my current city,country,location etc. I've already checked info's on developer.android.com related with location issues but the problem persists.

Here is the code; any ideas? thanks..

```
  package com.kodlab.nerdeyim;

  import android.location.Location;
  import android.os.AsyncTask;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

   import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult; 
   import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
   import  com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
   import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
   import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
   import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ConnectionCallbacks,    OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private LocationClient locationClient;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
              .setInterval(5000)
              .setFastestInterval(500)
              .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);   
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    HaritadaKonumGosterAsyncTask task = new HaritadaKonumGosterAsyncTask();
    task.execute(new Location[] {location});
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if(locationClient.isConnected())
        locationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);

    locationClient.disconnect();
}

private class HaritadaKonumGosterAsyncTask  extends AsyncTask<Location, Void, LatLng> {

    @Override
    protected LatLng doInBackground(Location... params) {
        Location konum = params[0];
        return new LatLng(konum.getLatitude(), konum.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(LatLng konum) {
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(konum, 15));
    }

}


 }
```

Comment: you are getting wrong Latlng in ASycn

Comment: This is what Google Maps does. It starts over Africa. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set it in your XML layout also (sets the middlish of North America):

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:cameraBearing="0"
    map:cameraTargetLat="53.938305"
    map:cameraTargetLng="-112.763672"
    map:cameraTilt="30"
    map:cameraZoom="2" />
```

I'm using the android maps extension in that example. Great library BTW. I really like this approach as it loads it right away and you never see Africa. IMO it seems to be the best.

Note! I should warn you that I get a compile error until I make a space and then save the file again when I start Eclipse up after I'm done for the day... Anyone know why this is?

Comment: I can't understand why this is the accepted answer and even why it has 3 upvotes. Don't get me wrong @jasonflaherty, your post is somehow helpful, but it doesn't answer the question (which asks for pointing to the current position, not a static position) at all

Comment: Hi Cliff, The question asked how to start elsewhere than Africa, do I assumed he was in US. I see what you are saying here. One could get their location first, then load the map.

Comment: Downvoted, answer does not say anything about focusing user location.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to your code solved my problem, now I help

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
  // Getting latitude of the current location
  double latitude = location.getLatitude();

  // Getting longitude of the current location
  double longitude = location.getLongitude();

  float speed = location.getSpeed();

  // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
  LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

  // Showing the current location in Google Map
  CameraPosition camPos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))   
    .zoom(18)        
    .bearing(location.getBearing())
    .tilt(70)
    .build();
  CameraUpdate camUpd3 = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos);
  googleMap.animateCamera(camUpd3);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a  AsycTask for this  remove it and do everything in `onlocationchanged()`  method itself

```
     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
         {
             googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 15));
           }
```